# Creating child controllers

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure if I'm thinking about my problem incorrectly, but basically here it is: I have a pen and paper gaming site I've built in PHP that I'm converting to Angular. I have one particular set of pages (for character sheets, displaying and editing) that are hit, then based on URL parameters, instantiate one of a few dozen subclasses, and call a common function among them. This function displays the page according to that subclasses template and logic. Example:

URL: /characters/dnd4/5/

When someone hits /characters/(anything)/ the site looks up (anything) to see if its a valid system, and instantiates an object of class **(anything)Character**, which is a child of **Character**. **Character** has a method called *displayEdit* which in **(anything)Character** calls the correct template for that system. Then everything gets carried down: functionality common to all characters (or a set of characters) is shared by parent classes, which can go up 2-3 tiers before hitting **Character**.

In PHP, this was just a case of having everything hit a set of common parents, but basic logic for the page is in the **Character** class, and then specific actions in the child classes. I'm having trouble figuring out how to map this in Angular. So far, I've just been creating controllers that do the logic for their page; I'm not sure how to set this up for logic being split to other functionality. I thought about making each option a directive, but can a directive be called dynamically? Should I be creating JS classes that operate the same? Can they carry the $scope from controllers?

All in all, I'm just not sure how to tackle this, or I've just overthought this so much I can't see an obvious solution.

Comment: Code that gets shared between controllers are best written in services. So you can have a `Character` service that you inject into your controllers, so that they can all share the same logic without repeating yourself. Without more details about how your app is structured its hard to give advice beyond that. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: I thought about services, but I'm not sure how to apply them to this situation... like I said, in PHP, I'm creating a have a parent class that never gets instantiated, but rather has child classes, so the common functions are in the parent, the specific functions are in the child classes. I'm not sure how that would split up into services. What sort of structure information would you like to help clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

Class inheritance in JavaScript can be done in a few ways. Creating closures with private variables and returning accessor methods is one such way, as opposed to [prototyical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). In Angular, you can abstract all your class logic into a service, then pass it into your controllers which will create the relevant view by loading a particular template & populating the correct information. [Here is an example of creating a base class, a couple of sub-classes, and a sub-sub-class](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/wagYQb?editors=101). I did not include templates, as this is simply a matter of calling a particular template file (via `ng-include` or by directive), but the general idea is here.

Update: [The more succinct, ES6 version of the code](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/xGgQGp?editors=001)

```
// Module
angular.module('app', [])

// Service 
function characterService () {
  return {
    character: function (spec) { // base class
      var type = spec.type || 'untyped'
      var name = spec.name || 'unnamed'
      var stats = {
        health: 10,
        mana: 10
      }
      return {
        getType: function () {
          return type
        },
        getName: function () {
          return name
        },
        getStats: function () {
          return stats
        },
        setStats: function (newStats) {
          stats = newStats
        }
      }
    },
    // sub class of character
    elf: function (spec) { 
      spec.type = spec.type || 'Elf'
      var elf = this.character(spec)
      var stats = elf.getStats()
      stats.health += 10
      elf.setStats(stats)
      elf.attack = function () {
        return 'You have shot an arrow!'
      }
      return elf
    },
    // sub class of character
    mage (spec) {
      spec.type = spec.type || 'Mage'
      var mage = this.character(spec)
      var stats = mage.getStats()
      stats.mana += 10
      mage.setStats(stats)
      mage.attack = function () {
        return 'Woah! Magic missile!!'
      }
      return mage
    },
    // sub class of mage
    warlock (spec) {
      spec.type = 'Warlock'
      var warlock = this.mage(spec)
      var stats = warlock.getStats()
      stats.mana += 10
      warlock.setStats(stats)
      warlock.attack = function () {
        return 'Cthulhu is summoned!'
      }
      return warlock
    }
  }
}

//Register Service
angular.module('app').factory('characterService', characterService)

// Main Controller
function main ($scope, characterService) {
  $scope.player1 = characterService.elf({name:'Erik'})
  $scope.player2 = characterService.mage({name:'Aayla'})
  $scope.player3 = characterService.warlock({name:'Zenthyr'})
}

// Register controller
angular.module('app').controller('main', main)
```